# How do you create a new struct?

Tags: solidity, struct

noob solidity question… if I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Special {
    string name;
    address[] deals;
    mapping (address => string[5]) dealNames;
}
```

how can I initialize a new "Special" with an empty deals array and empty dealNames mapping, having only a string for name.

I've tried this and it errors out (obviously?)

```
Special special = Special({
    name: "bingo",
    deals: [],
    dealNames: {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise the Struct like this:

```
address[] memory addresses;
Special memory s = Special("Test", addresses);
```

There a section in the [FAQ of the Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html?highlight=struct#can-state-variables-be-initialized-in-line) that you might also find useful.